# Assigning a Function into an Array

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I assign a function after `</section>`? Into the array?

```
<?php
function roots_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'          => __('Footer', 'roots'),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-footer',
        'before_widget' => '<section class="widget span4 %1$s %2$s"><div class="widget-inner">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div></section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h3>',
       'after_title'   => '</h3>', 
    ));
}
?>
```

Edit #1 (I came up with this, but it's not working properly. I'm trying to spawn `</div><div class="row-fluid">` every 3 wigets / sections.):

```
<?php
$i = 1;
function name () {
    if($i % 3 == 0) {
        return "</div><div class=\"row-fluid\">";
    } else {
    return;  
    }
    $i++;   
}
function roots_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'          => __('Footer', 'roots'),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-footer',
        'before_widget' => '<section class="widget span4 %1$s %2$s"><div class="widget-inner">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div></section>' . name(),
        'before_title'  => '<h3>',
       'after_title'   => '</h3>', 
    ));
}
?>
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: What exactly is it that you mean with "assign" ? Is it as simple as `'after_widget'  => '</div></section>' . my_function()` ?

Comment: I just edited my post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While im not 100% sure what you're asking you can place return values of functions anywhere you like.

```
function roots_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'          => __('Footer', 'roots'),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-footer',
        'before_widget' => '<section class="widget span4 %1$s %2$s"><div class="widget-inner">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div></section>' . get_after_section(),
        'before_title'  => '<h3>',
        'after_title'   => '</h3>', 
    ));
}
```

Will append the return value of `get_after_section` to the current value of 'after_widget'.

Comment: @johnwhs Edit #1 (I came up with this, but it's not working properly. I'm trying to spawn `</div><div class="row-fluid">` every 3 wigets / sections.)

Comment: The `$name` variable is not global. It won't be accessible from `name()`. I don't know what the environment of your application is, therefore I can't really give your more hints.